# UI Not updating after raising OnPropertyChanged

Tags: .net, wpf, timer, ui-thread, worker-thread

I need to run something every 5 seconds have the UI update

```
    public ViewModelCtor()
    {
       var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000)
        {
            Enabled = true
        };

        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            TimeSinceLastLogin = CalculateTimeSinceLastLogin();
        };


    public string TimeSinceLastLogin
    {
        get { return _timeSinceLastLogin; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _timeSinceLastLogin) return;
            _timeSinceLastLogin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TimeSinceLastLogin)));
        }
    }
```

CalculateTimeSinceLastLogin just sets the TimeSinceLastLogin property to a value. Nothing special.

The timer executes on a worker thread and so the UI does not update from what I can tell. What should I do in order for the UI to update? My solution needs to be agnostic as it could target wpf or xamarin.

Comment: This works fine for me with a TextBlock's Text property bound to TimeSinceLastLogin.

Comment: Looks fine. Could you post the code where you bind to TimeSinceLastLogin, because I can only guess that there's something wrong with the binding. Also, could you show the class declaration? What does ViewModelCtor inherit from?

Comment: Also, have you checked if TimeSinceLastLogin's setter actually gets called every 5 seconds?

Comment: My best guess is that your ViewModel doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Yes my problem was unrelated to this firing on a background thread. I created a new project with everything stripped back to basics and it worked fine.My issue was a naming issue in the underlying binding. Thanks